# Dos return en una function de laravel

Tags: php, laravel

necesito saber si se puede y como devolver tanto los usuarios como la vista

```
public function show()
{
    //

    $data['usuarios'] = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rol = 2");

     return $data['usuarios'];
     return view('usuarios.list');
     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Dentro de una función/método no pueden existir múltiples return, es solo uno y este deberá ser capaz de devolver el resultado del procesamiento interno
- Laravel ya ofrece una sintaxis para retornar valores a través del método `view` al cual como segundo argumento le podemos pasar la data que planeamos mandar a la vista

Entonces debería quedar así:

```
return view('tu-vista', ["clave" => $variable]);
```

Donde `$variable` es la que esta almacenando el resultado de tu consulta, recomiendo leas [este apartado de la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#passing-data-to-views) donde de hecho puedes ver mas opciones para lograr lo que buscas.

Para el caso de [**`return`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.returning-values.php) te recomiendo la documentación de PHP pues finalmente este es el le guaje base de Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendido que no se puede hacer dos return, pero lo que si puedes es tratar de meterlo a un JSON como arreglo y al recibirlos ya separarlos.